# How correctly to cast the _foo to `Foo` type?

Tags: javascript

I write the `Foo` instance to JSON and recovery back. Then I try to use instance's method but I get the error:

```js
class Foo{
 constructor(name,surname){
  this.name=name;
    this.surname=surname;
  };
  fullName(){
   return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
  };
};

let foo = new Foo('John', 'Smith');
console.log(foo.fullName());

let json = JSON.stringify(foo);
let _foo = JSON.parse(json);

Object.setPrototypeOf(_foo, Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo));

// Uncaught TypeError: _foo.fullName is not a function
console.log(_foo.fullName());
```

How correctly to cast the _foo to `Foo` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// JS6
class Foo{
 constructor(name,surname){
  this.name=name;
  this.surname=surname;
 };
  fullName(){
   return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
  };
};

let foo = new Foo('John', 'Smith');
console.log(foo.fullName());

let json = JSON.stringify(foo);
let _foo = JSON.parse(json);

Object.setPrototypeOf(_foo, Foo.prototype);

console.log(_foo.fullName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Object.assign(...)`:

```
function foo() { }

const parsedFoo = Object.assign(new foo(), JSON.parse(myJson));
// parsedFoo instanceof foo === true
```